# PostgreSQL function return type

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm trying to define a function along the lines of:

```
CREATE FUNCTION myfunction(list_of_ids integer[]) RETURNS record AS $$
  SELECT a.col1, b.col2 FROM a, b WHERE col1 = ANY($1);
$$ LANGUAGE 'sql'
```

However postgres doesn't seem happy with "record" as the return type, giving me this error when I try to execute the function:

```
ERROR:  a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"
```

Looking through the docs though I can't work out how to supply this column definition list.

Comment: This would be more instructive if you showed the statement where you execute the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a prepared query for this instead - all I really wanted was to ensure that the overhead of parsing the query and generating the query plan each time was eliminated, so a prepared statement worked fine for that.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, your query seems off: no **JOIN condition** for tables `a` and `b`? You don't want a Cartesian product, do you? Try something like:

```
SELECT a.col1, b.col2
FROM   a
JOIN   b ON <some condition like b.a_id = a.a_id>
WHERE  col1 = ANY($1);
```

Next, use a **return type** for the function so you don't have to provide a column definition list for every call. In the example I make use of `RETURNS TABLE`. Read about [more ways in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING).
Could look like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION myfunction(list_of_ids integer[])
 RETURNS TABLE (
  col1 text -- has to match the type of the column a.col1 that is returned.
 ,col2 text -- match type of a.col2
) AS
$$
  SELECT a.col1, b.col2
  FROM   a
  JOIN   b ON <some condition like b.a_id = a.a_id>
  WHERE  col1 = ANY($1);
$$
  LANGUAGE sql;
```

The single quotes around 'sql' are just noise. It can function as a key word.

Now you can call:

```
SELECT * FROM  myfunction('{11,23,6}'::integer[]);
```